# backbone on rails with persistence

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have an app that I'm building and would like to implement rails persistence to the backbone front end.

can someone point me to a simple repo or tutorial where i can learn about the configuration needed in rails to be able to persist data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at the [backbone-rails](https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) gem.

It also provides a backbone:scaffold generator (I find that many rails generators can be used like "tutorial").